# TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable for BytesIO() stream

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return a response to a user can download the CSV from the browser. Even though I am successfully making a CSV for some response when I return the response I get the error `TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable`

```
    from flask import make_response
    import csv
    from io import BytesIO

    new_csvfile = BytesIO()
    wr = csv.writer(new_csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in result:
        wr.writerow(row)

    #print new_csvfile.getvalue()

    output = make_response(new_csvfile.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

I am writing the CSV into a stream BytesIO() and its successfully creating a csv from what im seeing. But when I return the response to the user in the browser I get the following error `TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable`

the `result` variable contains the data that I am writing to an CSV

If I have `print new_csvfile.getvalue()` the csv is fine and returns the below:

```
"1","2","3","4","5"
"1","2","3","4","5"
```

Comment: please also add the jinja template where your are handling the csv response.

Comment: On the jinja side i just put     `<a href="/getactivitycsv"> download csv </a> which requests the url from the controller`

Comment: @soniccool why don't want to use just `Response + generator` without BytesIO and make_response(`return Response(your_function)`)?

Answer (score -1):

`make_response` doesn't support `BytesIO` type object. It takes the `Response` type and some other args like status code and headers. Modified code with `jsonify` for creating `Response` object.

```py
    from flask import make_response, jsonify
    import csv
    from io import BytesIO

    new_csvfile = BytesIO()
    wr = csv.writer(new_csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in result:
        wr.writerow(row)

    resp_data = {
        'data': new_csvfile.getvalue()
    }
    output = make_response(jsonify(resp_data))
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

Some reference links for more info.

[make response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response)

[kite docs](https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.make_response)

Comment: Got this error, `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
 
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.`

How should I request it on the jinja side? Just put the URL of what hits the controler?

Comment: Where is your result that you are iterating. I just used the same code from you question which is actually not working code. also where are your routes?